Condition for sequential approximate identity for $C_0(\Omega)$
Exercise 1.4.1 (p.21) of Conway's A Course in Operator Theory asks for a necessary and sufficient condition that $C_0(X)$ have a sequential approximate identity, where $X$ is assumed to be locally compact. (At this stage of the book, only elementary approaches can be used. So no mention of irreducible representation etc... is allowed yet.)
I know it doesn't matter if $X$ is Hausdorff or not, since we can always consider its Kolmogorov quotient, $\hat{X}$, and there is a natural isomorphism of $C^*$-algebras from $C_0(X)$ to $C_0(\hat{X})$. Because every $f\in C_0(X)$ takes constant value on two points without mutually disjoint neighborhoods. Then, consider the one-point compactification $\hat{X}\cup \{\infty\}$, which is compact Hausdorff, hence completely regular. Then, for every compact $\hat{K}\subset \hat{X}$, there is a continuous function $\hat{f}_\hat{K}:  \hat{X}\cup \{\infty\} \to [0,1]$, s.t. $\hat{f}_\hat{K}|_\hat{K}=1$ and $\hat{f}_\hat{K}(\infty)=0$. These functions, once pulled back to functions in $C_0(X)$, with their natural order, then form an approximate identity.
Therefore, I'm tempting to answer the condition to be $X=\cup K_n$, where $K_1\subset \cdots \subset K_n\subset \cdots$ are a sequence of nested compact sets. This is preserved after taking Kolmogorov quotient.

Q1. should I call the above condition hemicompact or $\sigma$-compact in this context?? Are $\sigma$-compactness and hemicompactness equivalent under the pre-condition of local compactness?


Q2. Is it really necessary to go to the Kolmogorov quotient? I did so because local compactness alone is not enough for being completely regular. Is it overkill?

Thanks in advance.

For Q1, I believe that the condition, as stated, is just $\sigma$-compactness. However, as you have suspected, every locally compact $\sigma$-compact space is hemicompact see e.g. here.
For Q2, I believe that it is safe to assume that everything is meant to be Hausdorff (precisely for the reason you mentioned).

Thanks for the link. Also, I just found out the precise concept for that property is called "exhaustible by (countable) compact sets", as in this wikipage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets.
